# Docker login to local Artifactory 403

Tags: docker, artifactory

I installed the evaluation Artifactory Pro in my local Windows laptop, I didn't create an reverse proxy, created the default Docker repos w/o any issue. The local repo is called docker-local, remote called docker-remote and the virtual called docker.

Try to follow the instructions here: https://jfrog.com/blog/how-to-set-up-a-private-remote-and-virtual-docker-registry/, I am getting the following error.

```
C:\Users\alexh>docker login localhost-docker.jfrog.io
Username: admin
Password:
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://localhost-docker.jfrog.io/v2/ failed with status: 403 Forbidden
```

What's my ${SERVER_NAME} in the command below?
docker login ${SERVER_NAME}-${VIRTUAL_REPO_NAME}.jfrog.io

Comment: If you are runnning a self-hosted instance, the url cannot be a jfrog.io one. Which URL did you use to access the UI? If it's on your local machine, you will need to use some real domain so that artifactory can extract the repo information...

Comment: I finally found the info from:
http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/admin/configuration/reverse_proxy

I am using Repository Path as the access method, so the following command work now:

docker login -u admin -p xxxx 10.0.0.79:8081

Comment: @user1288329 what is the 10.0.0.79 from?